# IIS Virtual Directory pointing to a local path vs UNC path

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I'm really stuck with the following and would appreciate any feedback.

I have a Silverlight application that uses [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoderpro_overview.aspx) to play video files.

When I deploy the source files to a local folder on my web server (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySLApp) and point my IIS virtual directory to this path, I can browse to my SL app and it plays video files as expected.

When I deploy the exact same source files to a network share (\fileserver\c$\content\MySLApp) and point my IIS virtual directory to this path, I can still browse to my SL app, but it **doesn't** play the video files.

NOTES:

- My web server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit
- I have installed Expression Encoder on my web server
- I have installed the Desktop Exprience feature
- My application pool is running under a custom user that has full access to the local machine and the network share.
- My application pool allows 32-bit applications
- My application pool Loads User Profile
- My Virtual Directory Physical Path Credentials is running under the same custom user as my application pool.

I just can't figure out/understand, why my SL app will work perfectly when pointing to a local folder, but when pointing to a UNC path, it still works, but the Expression Encoder functionality doesn't work.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SilverLight uses ASP.NET, you probably need to run caspol.exe to allow the custom user access to the file server.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/50/aspnet-20-35-shared-hosting-configuration/